# How to lock Windows 7 with second screen displaying actual desktop?

Tags: display, lock

I have special PC for testing purposes, it has two screens: one (main) for displaying virtual machines which operate tests, another (2nd) for graphs.

I'd like the second one to be always on (should always display graphs), even when I go away and lock my PC.

**Is it even possible?**

**P.S.:** there could be another problem, mozilla browser (which is used to display graphs) stops refreshing when PC is locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started to use 3rd party software to lock keyboard & mouse with password.

In my case it is `Kid-Key-Lock`, I was choosing between several software but this is one that uses password (whatever you want to set) for locking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to keep one screen unlocked in this way. Windows basically swaps your visable desktop with a different one when the machine is locked.

You may be able to display the graphs using a screensaver, however.

Comment: there is no option in Windows 7 to display current desktop contents with screensaver (there is a stuff like photos, some flying geometry, etc.)

Comment: It would depend on how your graphs are being generated. If you can convert them to images, you can use the images screensaver. You could also look for a 3rd party screensaver.